# Excel IF Statement not returning expected result:

Tags: excel

I have the following formula that I need help with. Any help is appreciated

The formula below will return zero because obviously 5 is not 3 etc:

```
=IF(5=3,5,IF(6=4,7,IF(3=5,8,"0")))
```

however when I add another IF then it returns an incorrect value. It returns "T" which should be returning 0.:

```
=IF(IF(5=3,5,IF(6=4,7,IF(3=5,8,"0")))>0,"T",0)
```

Comment: remove the quotes around `"0"`.  a string is always greater than a number.

Comment: @Scott, As usual. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because:

="0">0

returns ***True***

Answer (score 0):

My advice: Don't use nested IF statements. Use a simple VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH instead. It's simpler to understand *and* it' more efficient.